# Arithmetic Circuits (ADDERS!)

Tags: adder, carry-look-ahead

I usually only become a passive reader in this forum, but today I decided to ask my first question.

***How many logic gates required for a 4-bit Carry Look Ahead adder and Prefix adder?***

I know that Carry Ripple adder required 5 logic gates because it's basically a series of full adder.

However, when I looked up on internet for CLA and Prefix there are variety of answers that make me confuse instead.

Any answers or comments will definitely help me. Thanks!

Comment: Share your confusion with links to that which confused you.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there are a lot of references to Carry Look Ahead adder and Prefix adders,
such as the the Ladner-Fischer adder and Kogge-Stone adder.

How everywhere I looked, it seemed these were shown only as block diagrams.

But I finally found a real gate diagram [here](http://robey.lag.net/2012/11/14/how-to-add-numbers-2.html) for a Kogge-Stone adder which might help you:

[image]

These is for a 8-bit adder, but you should be able to cut it to 4-bits easily.